# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I'm launching my project, I was faced with the error:

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {
    Formik,
    Field,
    Form,
    useField,
    FieldAttributes,
    FieldArray
} from "formik";
import {
    TextField,
    Button,
    Checkbox,
    Radio,
    FormControlLabel,
    Select,
    MenuItem
} from "@material-ui/core";
import * as yup from "yup";

type MyRadioProps = { label: string } & FieldAttributes<{}>;

const MyRadio: React.FC<MyRadioProps> = ({ label, ...props }) => {
    const [field] = useField<{}>(props);
    return <FormControlLabel {...field} control={<Radio />} label={label} />;
};

const MyTextField: React.FC<FieldAttributes<{}>> = ({
                                                        placeholder,
                                                        ...props
                                                    }) => {
    const [field, meta] = useField<{}>(props);
    const errorText = meta.error && meta.touched ? meta.error : "";
    return (
        <TextField
            placeholder={placeholder}
            {...field}
            helperText={errorText}
            error={!!errorText}
        />
    );
};

const validationSchema = yup.object({
    firstName: yup
        .string()
        .required()
        .max(10),
    pets: yup.array().of(
        yup.object({
            name: yup.string().required()
        })
    )
});

const App: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Formik
                validateOnChange={true}
                initialValues={{
                    firstName: "",
                    lastName: "",
                    isTall: false,
                    cookies: [],
                    yogurt: "",
                    pets: [{ type: "cat", name: "jarvis", id: "" + Math.random() }]
                }}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}
                // validate={values => {
                //   const errors: Record<string, string> = {};

                //   if (values.firstName.includes("bob")) {
                //     errors.firstName = "no bob";
                //   }

                //   return errors;
                // }}
                onSubmit={(data, { setSubmitting }) => {
                    setSubmitting(true);
                    // make async call
                    console.log("submit: ", data);
                    setSubmitting(false);
                }}
            >
                {({ values, errors, isSubmitting }) => (
                    <Form>
                        <MyTextField placeholder="first name" name="firstName" />
                        <div>
                            <Field
                                placeholder="last name"
                                name="lastName"
                                type="input"
                                as={TextField}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <Field name="isTall" type="checkbox" as={Checkbox} />
                        <div>cookies:</div>
                        <Field
                            name="cookies"
                            type="checkbox"
                            value="chocolate chip"
                            as={Checkbox}
                        />
                        <Field
                            name="cookies"
                            type="checkbox"
                            value="snickerdoodle"
                            as={Checkbox}
                        />
                        <Field name="cookies" type="checkbox" value="sugar" as={Checkbox} />
                        <div>yogurt</div>
                        <MyRadio name="yogurt" type="radio" value="peach" label="peach" />
                        <MyRadio
                            name="yogurt"
                            type="radio"
                            value="blueberry"
                            label="blueberry"
                        />
                        <MyRadio name="yogurt" type="radio" value="apple" label="apple" />
                        <FieldArray name="pets">
                            {arrayHelpers => (
                                <div>
                                    <Button
                                        onClick={() =>
                                            arrayHelpers.push({
                                                type: "frog",
                                                name: "",
                                                id: "" + Math.random()
                                            })
                                        }
                                    >
                                        add pet
                                    </Button>
                                    {values.pets.map((pet, index) => {
                                        return (
                                            <div key={pet.id}>
                                                <MyTextField
                                                    placeholder="pet name"
                                                    name={`pets.${index}.name`}
                                                />
                                                <Field
                                                    name={`pets.${index}.type`}
                                                    type="select"
                                                    as={Select}
                                                >
                                                    <MenuItem value="cat">cat</MenuItem>
                                                    <MenuItem value="dog">dog</MenuItem>
                                                    <MenuItem value="frog">frog</MenuItem>
                                                </Field>
                                                <Button onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)}>
                                                    x
                                                </Button>
                                            </div>
                                        );
                                    })}
                                </div>
                            )}
                        </FieldArray>
                        <div>
                            <Button disabled={isSubmitting} type="submit">
                                submit
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                        <pre>{JSON.stringify(values, null, 2)}</pre>
                        <pre>{JSON.stringify(errors, null, 2)}</pre>
                    </Form>
                )}
            </Formik>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

**index.tsx**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I have googled it and don't find an appropriate answer

Comment: Can you try React.FC<{}> for your App?

Comment: No, can you please explain, I need to use it like this?
const App: React.FC<{}> =() => {}

Comment: Something interesting is that you `App.js` yet trying to use `TypeScript` in there. Please rename the file to `App.tsx` especially if you have `TypeScript` already installed. The update this line `const App: React.FC<{ // add interface }> = () => {}`. Hopefully, it now makes sense.

Comment: TS7010: 'return', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.